# Change checkbox visibility not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following code hiding rows in a sheet, but the sheet is left with its dynamically created checkboxes still visible. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
week = Me.Range("b1").Value
countcell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
For i = 4 To countcell
  pweek = Me.Cells(i, 2).Value    'load the planned week value
  mycont = "ckboxPrintLabels" & i
  If pweek <> week Then
    CheckBoxes(mycont).Visible = False
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    MsgBox mycont & "= " & ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(mycont).Visible
  Else
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(mycont).Visible = True
  End If
  k = i
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So currently I have ckboxPrintLabels4 thru to 16 on the sheet. They fail to change visibility. Although the msgbox reports that they have visibility at false...???

Comment: btw it's Excel 2003, and dynamic code for checkbox creation looks like this:
` ' snipped to fit in comments
  For Each cell In ws.Range("g" & Lower & ":g" & Upper)
  With ws.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, _
     cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
     .LinkedCell = ""
     .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     .Caption = ""
     .name = "ckboxPrintLabels" & ckbox
     .Visible = True
  End With
  ckbox = ckbox + 1
  Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`

Comment: please don't add [solved] and stuff the answer in the question section, you can add & accept your own answer

Comment: Sathya...thanks for clearing that up for me. It had me confused when unable to post again because of low score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked that all the visible checkboxes are actually named ckboxPrintLabelsX etc

I ran your code twice as in the first run I handn't named the boxes properly when I separated out your later commented code. The second run ***correctly*** hid the checkboxes with ckboxPrintLabelsX titles, but the other checkboxes with different titles (Check Box 1 etc) were still visible

A quick google throws up the a similar issue at http://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=103984. In this case as the checkboxes are stacked on the row hide, it appears one remanined visible on top.

---

Error was in creation code, creating more than one checkbox with same name. These would stack. When the hiding took place it only took effect on one set of controls.

```
    Public Sub addcheckboxes(ByVal Lower As String, ByVal Upper As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, myObjectname As String, addChk As Boolean

    Set ws = Workbooks("nursery.xls").Worksheets("Seeding")
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     ckbox = Lower
     ' add a checkbox for printing
     For Each cell In ws.Range("g" & Lower & ":g" & Upper)

     myObjectname = "ckboxPrintLabels" & ckbox
     addChk = True

     For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
     ' nasty hack to overcome the limitations of vba in excel - no eval!
        If ctrl.name = myObjectname Then
        addChk = False ' if chkbox already exists
      ctrl.Visible = True 'switch to visible, as it may not be
      End If
       Next

    If addChk Then
    With ws.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, _
     cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
     .LinkedCell = cell
     .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     .Caption = ""
     .name = myObjectname
     .Visible = True
    End With
    End If
    ckbox = ckbox + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, you are quite right. The creation is the problem. Edited main post to add good code.

Comment: cheers for the quick response and accept